# Click event not work if page resolution is changed, Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to learn Robotframework. My page has css **zoom:85%**. Now my Click Element is not working. It says that my clickable element is behind another element.

If I remove zoom:85%, then it works.

Please help. I am using `SeleniumLibrary`. I am finding my clickable button through xpath.

Answer (score 1):

That's regretfully a known issue for Chrome - [the stll-open bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=628). IE also explicitly states the zoom must be at 100% for the interactions to work.

In summary, when a click is to be done the browser's driver (the code controlling it) calculates the element's dimensions and position, and executes the click in its center. When the zoom is != 100% all these data points are different and it calculates wrong click coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using static xpath, you can provide a dynamic xpath. When you inspect element, you will find that the element must have an id or a value designated. The resolution wont be a factor if Robot has to search nothing but only id of the element.
For example:

```
<a id="nav-tags" href="/tags" class=" js-gps-track nav-links--link" data-gps-track="top_nav.click({is_current:false, location:2, destination:2})">
Tags</a>
```

Here the id is: id="nav-tags"
So you can define your xpath like:
xpath=//*[@id="nav-tags"]

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's really not so - xpath, css, by id or name, these are all different means to get to the same goal - having a reference to an element. And what exactly is the xpath expression that'll get the element - again, irrelevant in the light of this question.